# Apache Config to send sub dirs to different servers - mod_proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-config, mod-proxy

We use Apache as a reverse proxy server.  This has been working well, but I now need to have http://domain.com/sub1 proxy to serverA and http://domain.com/sub2 proxy to serverB.  Is this possible?  If so, what is the config for it?

Here is my existing config:

```
...
<VirtualHost 555.55.555.555:80>
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot c:/docroot

ProxyPass / http://serverA/
ProxyPassReverse / http://serverA/
</VirtualHost>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it.  You want something like:

```
ProxyPass /sub1 http://serverA/
ProxyPassReverse /sub1 http://serverA/
ProxyPass /sub2 http://serverB/
ProxyPassReverse /sub2 http://serverB/
```

Check out the documentation for the [ProxyPass directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), there are some neat tricks you can do with it.

Comment: I feel dumb.  It has only been 4 years since I've had to touch the config though...  Thank you!